# What's the equivalent of this.props.history.push in gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to do `this.props.history.push("/payment/" + stripe_plan_id)`

What is the equivalent of this.props.history.push in Gastby?

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: need more information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gatsby uses [reach router](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/reach-router-and-gatsby/). Try the following:

```
import { navigate } from "@reach/router"
```

---

```
navigate(`/payment/${stripe_plan_id.id}`)
```

Comment: Do you know how to create the dynamic page /payment/{ID} ?

Comment: Thanks @ksav. Do you know how to open that link on a new page? I mean what is the equivalent of target="_blank" for this?

Comment: Just use a regular link.

Comment: navigate doesn't work on `gatsby build`. Any workaround?

Comment: This doesn't work it throws an error that the page doesn't exist which does I've tested .

Comment: Could be related to this bug https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27196

Answer (score 14):

The top answer doesn't work anymore But this does work :

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
```

```
navigate(`/payment/${stripe_plan_id.id}`)
```

Comment: `navigate` is a property of props passed to all components. You can just do: ```props.navigate(`/payment/${stripe_plan_id.id}`)```