# How to push to url in gatsby js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

In react I've used to push with history prop like this :

```js
 <button onClick={() => props.history.push('/someurl')} >
```

I tried this way but it doensn't work :

```
import { navigate } from '@reach/router';

<button onClick={ () => navigate(`/`);} > Navigate < / button>
```

Error :

```
Gatsby.js development 404 page

There's not a page yet at /
```

I've also tried this url :

```
navigate(`localhost:8000/`);
```

But it throws this error in the console :

```
Failed to launch 'localhost:8000/' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.
```

It says the page doesn't exist but it does and I've checked it by putting the same url in browser and it does exist .

How can I push something to url in gatsby  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the equivalent of this.props.history.push in gatsby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58677568/whats-the-equivalent-of-this-props-history-push-in-gatsby)

Comment: @reisdev Actually that answer throws an error in console and doesn't work

Comment: Which error does it throw?

Comment: @reisdev I've edited the post with more information thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of importing `navigate` from `@reach/router`, use the [Gatsby-provided wrapper](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function):

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby"

const HomeButton = () => 
  <button onClick={() => navigate("/")}>
    Homeward!
  </button>
```

If you want to change the URL without keeping the previous page in history you can also pass the second argument an options object with `replace` set to a truthy value. E.g.:

```
const HomeButton = () => 
  <button onClick={() => navigate("/", { replace: true })}>
    Homeward!
  </button>
```